# PHP String Variable

Tags: php, variables

Cand we apply php constructs, and logic inside php string variable.... like

```
// php string variable:

$content = "Something in string........bla bla bala.......".
 while(.....){}
 ."agian string...";

echo $content;


// i am getting error => unexpected T_WHILE in my php....
```

Comment: In this case you should break it up or move the while condition and output into a separate function (which returns a string).

Comment: @* but how can we apply a login inside a single variable.

Comment: @mario, yes all this spliting of string i know but can we apply to a single variable. just like that.

Comment: @ime huh? you need to explain a bit more clearer than that! Your original question has been answered below. What you pertain to above sounds like a completely different issue. **Edit** That string is assigned to **one** variable. It's just string concatenation.

Comment: See what M42 wrote. You might have to concretise your example for alternative suggestions, it's too abstract. (Sometimes variable expressions are an option; though they don't simplify things.)

Comment: @mario, yes thats way is too pretty, but i was trying to do that single way, with every login on a single variable... but this is not happened. And the answers show that all agree upon that not possible.. so thanks... all of you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. But you can use a function :

```
function myFunction() {
    while(....) {
        ...
    }
    return $something;
}
$content = "Something in string........bla bla bala......." . myFunction() . "agian string...";
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do that but you could do this.

```
$content = "Something in string........bla bla bala.......";
while(.....){
    $content .= "agian string...";
}

echo $content;
```

Answer (score 2):

No. No, you can't.

Use string concatenation properly:

```
$content = "Start";
while (<something>) {
   $content .= "Middle";
}
$content .= "End";
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll have to append in a loop:

```
$content = "Something in string........bla bla bala.......";
while ($i++ < 20) {
    $content .= 'something else';
}
$content .= 'something to end';

echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, what the `while(...)`-part should do, but [implode()](http://php.net/implode) may help